# Javascript literal object execute method in another literal object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Well I'm no JS expert, but...I have 3 literal javascript objects:

1 Main search object and other 2 objects who work with that object and ask
for data.

The thing is - that I need to render the results differently so I set a different callbacks
inside each requesting object but I cant get the search object to trigger it.

Any ideas?

```
var Search = {

    Execute: function() {
    // logic

    // Set the result/data
    var $someObjectHere

    // Execute Callback
    if ( theCallback.indexOf('.') != -1 ) {
        // Its a method inside an object, trigger it.
        theCallback = theCallback.split('.');
        obj = theCallback[0];
        methodName = theCallback[1];
        obj[methodName]($someObject); <--- DOESNT WORK!
        }
    }
}

var Obj1 = {

    bind_events: function() {
        $('button1').on('click',function(){
            Search.theCallback = 'obj1.mycallback';
            Search.Execute();
        });
    },

    mycallback: function() {
        // CALLBACK!
    }
}

var Obj2 = {

    bind_events: function() {
        $('button1').on('click',function(){
            Search.theCallback = 'obj2.mycallback';
            Search.Execute();
        });
    },

    mycallback: function() {
        // CALLBACK!
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. You need to be working with function references, not string "paths".

Comment: Also in String reference you have lowercase first ketter, but object have uppercase. And some other mistakes

Comment: Has this been simplified? Why can't you just put `Obj1.mycallback()` - especially as the `Execute` method doesn't actually log or do anything special other than execute the function

Comment: OK, so How can I pass a method for callback execution? without passing a string "path"?

Comment: e.g.: `function myFunc(){}  Obj.bind_events(myFunc)` - the name of the function without the `()`

Comment: @Broshi: `Search.theCallback = Obj1.mycallback;`  Then `theCallback` is just a function, so you can call it like one.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks! that seems to do the job =)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was happy to early, I does execute the method but I cannot access the object that owns that method, so It just passes a `copy` of that method as a callback.

Comment: Here is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve, its not working properly:
http://jsfiddle.net/77ngZ/14/

Comment: You need to add `var self = this;` inside of `executeCallback`.  Also, you never set `self.callbackFunction` to anything.